# Нажать кнопку в Word с помощью VBS

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Нужно автоматически нажать кнопку в документе Word.

[image]

В уже открытом документе просто постоянно нажимать кнопку "Изменить". Если этой кнопки нет, то нажать "Пропустить" и опять продолжать нажимать первую кнопку.

Всё, что придумал, выглядит так:

```
Set shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Do
    If кнопка "изменить" существует Then
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate "Правильно.doc - Word (Сбой активации продукта)"

        'Вот здесь не знаю как выбрать кнопку и нажать на неё.

        else 
        нажать "пропустить"
        Exit Do
    End If
    WScript.Sleep 500
Loop
```

Но не знаю, как обозначить нужную кнопку.